# Brand new ASUS P8Z68-V Pro/Gen3 motherboard won't pass POST

Tags: motherboard, post

I am staring at some brand-new kit that doesn't want to play with me:

- Motherboard: ASUS P8Z68-V Pro/Gen3
- CPU: Intel i7-2600K
- RAM: 1 stick only of Corsair Vengeance 4GB 1600MHz (originally 4 sticks, but removed them during debugging.)
- PSU: Factory refurbished, 485 watt ATX Power supply Enermax EG495P-VE-SFMA Noisetaker II
- No drives (originally several unformatted SATA drives, but removed them during debugging)
- Onboard graphics card only.

The symptoms:

- Power supply fan, CPU fan and case fans all start up when I hit the On switch.
- **A warning light on the motherboard tells me it doesn't like the CPU.**
- No VGA output.
- No POST beep
- Often see the "double boot" that others have reported and dismissed as insignificant (powers up, for about two seconds, shuts down, and then powers up again a few seconds later).
- When drives were installed, they would start spinning.

So, it appears there might be something wrong with the CPU (or perhaps the motherboard). The manual is very vague about what the light might indicate.

The install was all fairly straightforward - no touching the pins, no dropping of the CPU onto the carpet, etc. - so while it is possible, I feel it is unlikely that I damaged anything.

Unfortunately, I don't have any other Intel 1155 motherboards or CPUs to cross-check that the CPU is actually good. Debugging this could be expensive!

To the best that I can tell, it is a compatible combination of models of motherboard and CPU. I'm hoping that there is some jumper/switch setting I may have missed, but I don't see anything relevant.

485W isn't the biggest power supply, but should be enough to power a motherboard, CPU and fans, which is all that is plugged in.

Short of buying replacement parts for items that may well be good, what other troubleshooting tips can people suggest.

Comment: The PSU is a refurb which suggests it was broken once - could it producing less watts than rated, or a flakey volts?  Is the mobo in a case?  If so, consider taking it out and laying in on some static free foam (like that which is in the mobo box.  It might be shorting somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a power-supply issue. No power was getting to the CPU.